# I can not break up the text on the page

Tags: android

I've got a question. text. for example

```
String str = "line1"+"\n" +
               "line2"+"\n" +
               "line3"+"\n" +
               "line4"+"\n" +
               "line5"+"\n" +
               "line6"+"\n" +
               "line7"+"\n" +
               "line8"+"\n" +
               "line9"+"\n" +
               "line10"+"\n" +
               "line11"+"\n" +
               "line12"+"\n" +
               "line13"+"\n" +
               "line14"+"\n" +
               "line15"+"\n" +
               "line16"+"\n" +
               "line17"+"\n";
```

I have a component that creates the page.
I need my text is divided into blocks (pages) and place it on the page. 
Now I work like that. I break the text into lines, and each page can place the line. But I need to break up the text such as 20 lines per 1 page. and these blocks of 20 lines displayed on a separate view. Now I work as follows:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();
String[] str1 = str.split("\n");
        View[] page1 = new View[7];
        TextView[] textView1 = new TextView[7];
         for (int i=1;i<page1.length;i++){
             page1[i] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
             textView1[i] = (TextView) page1[i].findViewById(R.id.text_view);
             textView1[i].setText(str1[i+1]);//then I do not need one row and 20
             pages.add(page1[i]);
         }
```

Comment: Better to use listview ..

Comment: and??????????????did not understand the answer

Comment: check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Comment: @user2954895: you need to use `ListView` to display this type of data. Refer this [Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90)

Comment: but it does not matter! I need to split the text on the page))) and in which componente show it does not matter! I have a text. it is big. I want to do n pages 20 lines each.

Comment: If I do not understand you, give a simple example code please!

Comment: http://habrastorage.org/storage1/61132d35/3ebc4005/633c15ac/f63b1e71.png